# How do i insert a checkbox in the IBM Watson Assistant?

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-watson, watson-assistant

I am using IBM Watson Assistant to create a troubleshooting guide. I wish to put a disclaimer in the beginning and only if the user checks the checkbox saying he agrees to the statements in the disclaimer, they will be able to go further in the conversation.

I tried include the HTML checkbox code, but it doesn't seem to work. I don't want "options" which is present in the Assistant. i wish to have a checkbox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that [Watson Assistant typically is part of a solution](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/services/assistant?topic=assistant-index) and not a chatbot alone. What is your app that is used as user interface? You could let your app react to a context variable and display the checkbox. Not all user interfaces and integrations may support displaying a checkbox.

Another option is to ask the user to agree to the terms. If they answer "I agree" or "Yes", then the dialog moves forward.